# Convert image to nvarchar(max)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a field that is defined as `longblob` in an MySQL database in which I upload pdf/word files/ etc.
However, I access this database from my SQL Server database and the data is accessed from a linked server and views.

**Problem**
The problem is, the data needs to be imported by another application, but the data type of the document file is coming across as image and that is causing a problem.

**What have I tried**

I have first tried to see if I change `longblob` to `varbinary` to get a `varbinary(max)` data type in SQL Server. That did not work, I still got image.

Then I tried to make a view of the view to convert the data. I tried `CAST(fileContent as varchar(max))` and got the error:

> Explicit conversion from data type image to nvarchar(max) is not allowed.

I then tried `cast(cast(fileContent as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) as fileContent` as I see suggested but I am getting back a ton of gibberish.

`%PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 3 0 obj <</Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 595.280 841.890] /TrimBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890] /Resources 2 0 R /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >>  /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 521>> stream xœµRËnÛ0Ü3¿b-ÐÐ|ŠRn ) 4¥==¨¶âºu’F1`

instead of something like `0x255044462D312E`,

Appreciate if I could get some assistance in converting binary data (which claims it's an image to `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)` are not suitable for binary data hence your gibberish, i.e.: store binary data in binary field types like `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: which appication language can't convert a blob into anything you like

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I used your answer so if you post as answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t table(theimage image)
insert into @t(theimage) 
values(0x3a26);


select convert(varchar(max), cast(theimage as varbinary(max)), 1) as theimagebinaryaschar
from @t;

declare @theimageaschar varchar(max) = '0x3a26';
select convert(varbinary(max), @theimageaschar, 1) as theimageasbinary;
```